# Laravel 5 pagination on raw query

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have a union query from 2 different tables which I have to run through raw query. But I am facing a problem in paginatig the result. Here's what I have done

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $result = \DB::select(\DB::raw("UNION query"));
        $result_p = Paginator::make($result , count($result), 10);
        return view('view_name',compact('result'));
    }
}
```

This gives an error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class does not contain the method `make()`.  Instead, pass those variables to the constructor.

```
$result_p = new Paginator($result, $resultsPerPage, $currentPage, $options);
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked. But what to do If I wanted To use the facade, i.e by using Paginator::make

Comment: That looks like a namespace issue.  The facades are in the global namespace so usually `\Facade::make()` should work.

Comment: @user3158900 Its working, but how to access the results, its showing protected.

Comment: Check out the API if you are trying to figure out how to do something.  https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html  Here it says it has a function `items()` which returns all the items being paginated.